# Computer Adaptive Testing 1PL Ability Calculation Math: How to implement?

Tags: math, stat

Preamble:

I have been implementing my own CAT system. The resources that have helped me most are these:

[An On-line, Interactive, Computer Adaptive Testing Tutorial, 11/98](http://echo.edres.org:8080/scripts/cat/catdemo.htm) -- A good explanation of how to pick a test question based on which one would return the most information. Fascinating idea, really. The equations are not illustrated with examples, however... but there is a simulation to play with. Unfortunately [the simulation](http://echo.edres.org:8080/scripts/cat/startcat.htm) is down!

[Computer-Adaptive Testing: A Methodology Whose Time Has Come](http://www.rasch.org/memo69.pdf) -- This has similar equations, although it does not use IRT or the Newton-Raphson Method. It is also Rasch, not 3PL. It does, however, have a BASIC program that is far more explicit than the usual equations that are cited. I have converted portions of the program in order to get my own system to experiment with, but I would prefer to use 1PL and/or 3PL.

[Rasch Dichotomous Model vs. One-parameter Logistic Model](http://www.rasch.org/rmt/rmt193h.htm) -- This clears some stuff up, but perhaps only makes me more dangerous at this stage.

---

Now, the question.

I want to be able to measure someone's ability level based on a series of questions that are rated at a 1PL difficulty level and of course the person's answers and whether or not they are correct.

I have to first have a function that calculates the probably of a given item. This equation gives the probability function for 1PL.

```
Probability correct = e^(ability - difficulty) / (1+ e^(ability - difficulty))
```

I'll go with this one arbitrarily for now. Using an ability estimate of 0, we get the following probabilities:

```
-0.3 --> 0.574442516811659
-0.2 --> 0.549833997312478
-0.1 --> 0.52497918747894
0 --> 0.5
0.1 --> 0.47502081252106
0.2 --> 0.450166002687522
0.3 --> 0.425557483188341
```

This makes sense. A problem targeting their level is 50/50... and the questions are harder or easier depending on which direction you go. The harder questions have a smaller chance of coming out correct.

Now... consider a test taker that has done five questions at this difficulty: -.1, 0, .1, .2, .1. Assume they got them all correct except the one that's at difficulty .2. Assuming an ability level of 0... I would want some equations to indicate that this person is slightly above average.

So... how to calculate that with 1PL? This is where it gets hard.

Looking at the equations on the various pages... I will start with an assumed ability level... and then gradually adjust it with each question after more or less like the following.

```
Starting Ability: B0 = 0

Ability after problem 1: B1 = B0 + [summations and function evaluated for item 1 at ability B0]

Ability after problem 2: B2 = B1 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-2 at ability B1]

Ability after problem 3: B3 = B2 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-3 at ability B2]

Ability after problem 4: B4 = B3 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-4 at ability B3]

Ability after problem 5: B5 = B4 + [summations and functions evaluated for items 1-5 at ability B4]
```

And so on.

Just reading papers on this, this is the gist of what the algorithm should be doing. But there are so many different ways to do this. The behaviour of my code is clearly wrong as I get division by zero errors... so this is where I get lost. I've messed with information functions and done derivatives, but my college level math is not cutting it.

Can someone explain to me how to do this part? The literature I've read is short on examples and the descriptions of the math appears incomplete to me. I suppose I'm asking for how to do this with a 3PL model that assumes that c is always zero and a is always 1.7 (or maybe -1.7-- whatever works.) I was trying to get to 1PL somehow anyway.

Edit: [A visual guide to item response theory](https://www.metheval.uni-jena.de/irt/VisualIRT.pdf) is the best explanation of how to do this I've seen so far, but the text gets confusing at the most critical point. I'm closer to getting this, but I'm still not understanding something. Also... the pattern of summations and functions isn't in this text like I expected.

Comment: http://www.rasch.org/memo69.pdf

Comment: I could definitely use an answer to this if anyone knows it.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this:

This is an inefficient solution, but it works and is reasonably inituitive.

The last link I mentioned in the edit explains this.

Given a probability function, set of question difficulties, and corresponding set of evaluations-- ie, whether or not they got it correct.

With that, I can get a series of functions that will tell you the chance of their giving that exact response. Now... multiply all of those functions together.

We now have a big mess! But it's a single function in terms of the unknown ability variable that we want to find.

Next... run a slew of numbers through this function. Whatever returns the maximum value is the test taker's ability level. This can be used to either determine the standard error or to pick the next question for computer adaptive testing.